# Fiddle fig transplant cutting and rooting

Tags: indoors, pruning, cuttings, repotting

So I have a 7ft fiddle fig plant that I purchased around six months ago. It grew around 5 feet since I got this and I would like to transplant it into the pot that you can see in the picture next to it.

I did create drainage holes.
I just want to know what soils I should use and should I use any rocks or something for a first layer under the soil.

Also I want to cut it down a little like 2 feet or so.
I would like to know where I should cut it and if I could root it and then plant it in the same pot once the cutting gets roots or can I plant it together right away?
[image]

Comment: Can anyone help here???